# Serve two separate sites on same domain with Pyramid+Nginx+Uwsgi

Tags: nginx, google-analytics, pyramid

I have two version of a website I would like to run tests on to see which overall layout users interact with more.  I will run these tests using google analytics and therefore am thinking that I need one site layout to be accessible as a sub-uri of the other.  For example, if users visit www.mysamplesite.com they would see one version of the site, and if they visit www.mysamplesite.com/grid they would see another version.

Is this even possible using Pyramid+Nginx+uwsgi?  If so, are there pointers as to how I would go about this (I've tried a number of things to no avail)?  Do I simply need to add a new .conf file for nginx that listens on a different port and then 'forward' that port from my standard server configuration.  In other words, if for my regular site configuration I have something like:

```
server{
    listen: 80;
    server_name www.mysamplesite.com;

    location /grid {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:81;
    }

 }
```

and then have another configuration file like:

```
server{
    listen: 81;
    server_name www.mysamplesite.com;


    location /grid{
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///blah
}
```

should something like that work so that the two site versions would be correctly served?  Obviously these aren't complete configuration files, just thoughts.  I've attempted a number of different configurations and feel like either this is not possible, or I am doing  dumb things.  Thanks for any pointers since I am clearly a bit new to this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are the code base of the sites same??
If the code base of the sites are same you can just map one more url `/grid` to your required views.

If the code bases are different you can simply serve them on the port 80 by something like this if i'm not wrong.

```
    server{
        listen: 80;
        server_name www.mysamplesite.com;

        location / {
            root /path/to/your/project/dir;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass /location/to/your/uwsgi/socket;  #or if your are using http-socket put that instead
        }            
        location /grid{
            root /path/to/your/project/dir2;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass /location/to/your/uwsgi/socket2;  #or if your are using http-socket put that instead
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you pygoku.  The code bases are different in significant enough ways that the views method didn't work for me.  I will tinker with your configuration suggestion after work this afternoon and see if it works.  Thanks again for your time.